# How to add new record to One2Many field automatically via create function in different model?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13, one2many

I have written a method **`_update_config_list`** which should automatically be called when a record has been created in **`account.analytic.line`**. This method should create a new record in the One2Many field if the `Employee` is not found in the One2Many field automatically.
But my code doesn't do anything.

```
from datetime import timedelta

from odoo import api, fields, models, tools
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, AccessError, ValidationError


class RoleSync(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'

    role_field_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Role', compute='_compute_role', comodel_name='project.roles')
    # role_addline = fields.Many2one('project.roles', compute="role_addline")
    remaining_time_id = fields.Float(related='task_id.remaining_hours', readonly=True,
                                     string="Time remaining  ")

    def _update_config_list(self):
        list_id = []
        for rec in self:
            if rec.project_id:
                list = self.env['project.project'].search(
                    [('name', '=', rec.project_id.name)])
                for val in list.list_id:
                    if rec.employee_id != val.emp_id:
                        list_id.append(rec.employee_id)
                list_id = set(list_id)
                list.update({'list_id': list_id})

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        result = super(RoleSync, self).create(values)
        self._update_config_list()
        return result
```

This is my class for the list_id:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from calendar import monthrange


from odoo import api, fields, models, tools
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, AccessError, ValidationError
from odoo.tools import date_utils


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


class ProjectClass(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.project'

    list_id = fields.One2many(
        'roles.roles', 'project_id', string="Config_List")

class RolesClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'roles.roles'

    emp_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")
    role_id = fields.Many2one('project.roles', string="Role")
    project_id = fields.Many2one(
        'project.project', string="Project", readonly='1')
```

[image: If a new record was created in this environment]
[image: It should automatically be added in this One2Many field]

Comment: It's difficult to understand your code without knowing what `list_id` is or will be. Please add the code (partly) about that stuff. And then there is a little mistake in the `create()`: you're calling `_update_config_list()` on `self`. This methods iterates on records, but `self` in this context (creation) is an empty recordset. You should call it on `result` instead, which is the recordsset of the created records.

Comment: Yes I forgot to include my code for the One2Many field which is my List. It has 3 fields, one is emp_id and I have to create a new entry automatically .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Odoo's X2Many notation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write

In your case it would be either 0 (create) or 4 (link):

```
rec.write({'list_id': [(0, 0, {values})]})

# OR

rec.write({'list_id': [(4, id)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like list.list_id = [(6, 0, list_id)] it replace the all records and list_id records more notation you can find on. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write

```
    def _update_config_list(self):
        list_id = []
        for rec in self:
            if rec.project_id:
                list = self.env['project.project'].search(
                    [('name', '=', rec.project_id.name)])
                for val in list.list_id:
                    if rec.employee_id != val.emp_id:
                        list_id.append(rec.employee_id)
                c = set(list_id)
                list.list_id = [(6, 0, list_id)]
```